# How to correctly pass arguments to a function? [batch]

Tags: command-line, batch-file, youtube-dl

I wrote myself a script that will download a playlist.
But I have two questions, and I do not know how to solve them.

- Why do I get an error if I enter a link of the form:
  `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL38DFE33C78765533`,
  I found out that the appropriation goes wrong, it divides the line into
  `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list` and `PL38DFE33C78765533`. How to make it work?
- Why the argument DOWNPATHLIST is incorrectly passed ?

---

```
SET DOWNPATHLIST= "%%(playlist_index)s - %%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
SET CACHDIR= ".cache"
SET /P id= Please, Enter ID or Link:
CALL :YOUTUBEDOWN %id%, "-f bestvideo[ext!=webm]??+bestaudio[ext!=webm]??/best[ext!=webm]", "-o %%DOWNPATHLIST%%"

:YOUTUBEDOWN
youtube-dl --cache-dir %CACHDIR% %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4 %~5
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems partly arises from

- inconsequent use of double quotes and
- the need to escape the `%` signs to not being interpreted as denoting
  a variable by doubling them `%%`.  But everytime cmd.exe parses a line
  set/call it reduces two `%%` to one `%`.
- Also the equal sign splits command line argumets (like ,;tab) and is
  removed.

---

Try this:

```
SET "DOWNPATHLIST=%%(playlist_index)s - %%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
SET "CACHDIR=.cache"
SET /P "id=Please, Enter ID or Link:"
CALL :YOUTUBEDOWN %id%, "-f bestvideo[ext!=webm]??+bestaudio[ext!=webm]??/best[ext!=webm]", "-o %%DOWNPATHLIST%%"
Pause
Goto :Eof
:YOUTUBEDOWN
youtube-dl --cache-dir %CACHDIR% %*
PAUSE
```

The `%*` will resolve all arguments passed unchanged.
To test you might temporarily prepend `youtube-dl` with an echo.

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than I thought. I didn't know that can use quotes in this form.

Comment: Well that seems to be specific to youtube-dl, make a try with no space following the `-o%%DOWNPATHLIST%%`

Comment: no, it does not work so that way. I already figured out, changed from `"-o %%DOWNPATHLIST%%"` to `-o "%%DOWNPATHLIST%%"` and it works for me.